# Why doesn't ls -l show the time and or year for every file?

Tags: rhel, ls, date

It annoys me that sometimes when I run `ls -l` on a folder it reports the date and time for some files and only the date and year for others.

```
$ ls -ltr
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle9 dba  173 Dec 22 09:49 a1.par
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle9 dba  191 Dec 22 09:49 a2.par
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle9 dba  185 Dec 22 09:49 a3.par
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle9 dba  497 Dec 22 09:49 a4.par
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle9 dba  238 Dec 22 09:49 a5.par
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle9 dba  260 Dec 22 09:49 a6.par
-rwxr-x--- 1 oracle9 dba 1076 Dec 22 09:49 al.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 oracle9 dba  931 Dec 22 09:49 im.sh
-rwxr-x--- 1 oracle9 dba  982 Dec 22 09:49 mt.sh
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle9 dba 4096 Dec 22 09:49 comp
drwxr-xr-x 2 oracle9 dba 4096 Dec 22 10:08 scr
-rw------- 1 oracle9 dba    0 Dec 22 10:25 nohup.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle9 dba    0 Dec 22 10:25 start
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle9 dba    0 Dec 22 10:25 start2
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle9 dba 5587 Dec 22  2016 g2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle9 dba 5725 Dec 22  2016 g2.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle9 dba    0 Dec 22  2016 t6.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle9 dba    0 Dec 22  2016 start6
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle9 dba    0 Dec 22  2016 g6.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle9 dba  781 Dec 22  2016 t2.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 oracle9 dba  730 Dec 22  2016 g6.out
```

Notice that *it doesn't show the time for the last 7 files* in the list, and that **it doesn't show the year for the first 14 files**.

This behavior is not always reproducible.

- How can this be avoided?
- Shouldn't the date/time format be consistent within the same list by default?

The OS is Red Hat 6.4

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The files listed with year have their modification dates in the future.

You can use the `--full-time` option to display the complete date.

Comment: future or over a 6 months old